# Silent mode priority only haywire

Tags: silent-mode, do-not-disturb

So recently my do not disturb priority only and silent mode keeps switching to just that from the volume being all the way up sometimes right before my eyes I can see it changing and all the settings are set to not go into silent mode never and then it'll switch to always just like that what is wrong with my phone? Please help!

Comment: You've probably installed an app that sets do-not-disturb mode automatically. Check in the settings what apps are installed.